# Drawing onto canvas% element

Tags: canvas, drawing, scheme, racket

I have a problem while trying to draw onto a canvas GUI element.

I create a frame, a canvas and try to draw on the dc context of the canvas with the `draw-line` method, but nothing happens. The frame with the canvas is shown, but the line isn't shown on the canvas.

```
(require racket/gui/base)

(define frame (new frame% [label "Frame"] [width 500] [height 500]))
(define canvas (new canvas% [parent frame]))
(define dc (send canvas get-dc))

(send dc draw-line 10 10 200 200)
(send frame show #t)
```

Does anybody know where I am wrong in the code above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(require racket/gui/base)

(define frame (new frame% [label "Frame"] [width 500] [height 500]))
(define canvas (new canvas% [parent frame]))
(define dc (send canvas get-dc))

(send frame show #t)
(sleep/yield 1)
(send dc draw-line 10 10 200 200)
```

It seems that you need to show the frame first and then wait a bit to let the window get ready.

Comment: This seems to be the solution, I can see a line now. Weird that this isn't mentioned in the Racket documentation. If I perform some drawing in the on-event callback of the `canvas%` class, it works imediately after intialising.

Comment: See the documentation on canvas<%> see my answer for a link.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that even though you can draw on the canvas outside
a call to on-paint method of the canvas, the effect is temporary.
Any window activity that require the window to refresh (such as moving, and resizing) can potentially erase your drawing.

Therefore: Draw everything from within the paint-callback.

```
#lang racket
(require racket/gui/base)

(define frame (new frame% [label "Frame"] [width 500] [height 500]))
(define canvas (new canvas% 
                    [parent frame]
                    [paint-callback 
                     (λ(can dc) (send dc draw-line 10 10 200 200))]))
(define dc (send canvas get-dc))
(send frame show #t)
```

See [Documentation on the canvas class](http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/canvas___.html?q=canvas) for further information.