# Transforming origin of drawing context

Tags: racket

I am trying to transform a `dc<%>` instance in order to set the origin (0,0) to be the lower left hand corner. In principle, [this question answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393173/scheme-racket-canvas-manipulation), however I am struggling to understand the detail of how it works as well as why I am seeing the behavior that I am. For starters, here is the code I am working with. Note that the line I draw starts from (0,0) in the upper left-hand corner.

```
#lang racket
(require racket/draw)


;;; Begin our drawing
(define w 200)
(define h 200)
(define dc (new pdf-dc%
                [interactive #f]
                [use-paper-bbox #f]
                [width w]
                [height h]
                [output "./foo.pdf"]))

(send dc start-doc "file output")
(send dc start-page)

(send dc draw-line 0 0 150 150)

(send dc end-page)
(send dc end-doc)
```

[image: Untransformed output]

From there, I believe I should be able to send my dc instance a `set-transformation` message with an appropriate transformation matrix. However, an appropriate transformation data structure that is still elusive to me.

The [documentation for `set-transformation`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/dc___.html?q=#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._racket%2Fdraw..rkt%29._dc~3c~25~3e%29._set-transformation%29%29) refers me to the documentation for [`get-transformation`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/dc___.html?q=#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._racket%2Fdraw..rkt%29._dc~3c~25~3e%29._get-transformation%29%29). Here I learn that I need to pass in a vector containing the initial transformation matrix, which I can retrieve via [`get-initial-matrix`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/draw/dc___.html?q=#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._racket%2Fdraw..rkt%29._dc~3c~25~3e%29._get-initial-matrix%29%29), and the transformation parameters x origin, y origin, x scale, y scale, and rotation.

My naive first attack on this has me constructing the transformation data structure as follows, getting the initial matrix via `get-initial-matrix` for the first part, and then flipping the y scale:

```
#lang racket
(require racket/draw)

;;; Begin our drawing
(define w 50)
(define h 50)
(define dc (new pdf-dc%
                [interactive #f]
                [use-paper-bbox #f]
                [width w]
                [height h]
                [output "./foo.pdf"]))

(send dc start-doc "file output")
(send dc start-page)

;(send dc get-transformation)
;; returns '#(#(1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0) 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0)

(send dc set-transformation
      (vector (send dc get-initial-matrix)
              0  0  ; x origin, y origin
              1  -1  ; x scale, y scale
              0))   ; rotation

(send dc draw-line 0 0 50 50)

(send dc end-page)
(send dc end-doc)
```

That results in an empty drawing, presumably with the line translated somewhere out of view.

Reading the comments on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393173/scheme-racket-canvas-manipulation), it suggests that I need to add an offset to the y origin (i.e. both the scale needs to be flipped and the origin translated). My next attempt adds this:

```
#lang racket
(require racket/draw)

;;; Begin our drawing
(define w 50)
(define h 50)
(define dc (new pdf-dc%
                [interactive #f]
                [use-paper-bbox #f]
                [width w]
                [height h]
                [output "./foo.pdf"]))

(send dc start-doc "file output")
(send dc start-page)

;(send dc get-transformation)
;; returns '#(#(1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0) 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0)

(send dc set-transformation
      (vector (send dc get-initial-matrix)
              0  h  ; x origin, y origin
              1  -1  ; x scale, y scale
              0))   ; rotation

(send dc draw-line 0 0 50 50)

(send dc end-page)
(send dc end-doc)
```

This appears to bring the drawing elements back into the frame, but I'm not *quite* at the origin:

[image: Flipped and translated]

In that drawing, I notice my origin still appears to be shifted vertically about a quarter of the way up the drawing context. I can add another bit to my y origin (excerpted from full example):

```
(send dc set-transformation
      (vector (send dc get-initial-matrix)
              0  (+ (* 0.25 h) h)  ; x origin, y origin
              1  -1  ; x scale, y scale
              0))   ; rotation
```

That looks pretty okay, but still perhaps a little off:

[image: Translated, flipped, and with added fudge-factor]

The last comment in the linked SO thread suggests that I need to supply a function that modifies the *initial* transformation matrix. This makes little sense to me, as I infer from the documentation that the initial transformation matrix is a starting point, not an ending point. Also, at this point, it seems like quite a lot of additional effort to do something that seems like it should be simple, and that seems logical that would be part of a function like set-transformation.

Sorry for the lengthy question context here, but I'm hoping someone can show me where I'm trivially misunderstanding something that's otherwise obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is the correct one. You simply missed a small detail.

PDF and postscript files often are meant to be printed. Printed documents need a margin (the printer needs grab the edge of the paper). The settings in `(current-ps-setup)` is used for the paper size, margin size and the scaling. Setting the scaling to 1 and the margin size to 0 will give you the results you expected.

```
#lang racket
(require racket/draw)

;;; Begin our drawing
(define w 200)
(define h 200)

(define setup (new ps-setup%))
(send setup set-paper-name "Peter")
; introduce margins such that the result is centered
(define α 1) ; a scale, try 0.9 to see how it works
(send setup set-margin (/ (* (- 1 α) w) 2) (/ (* (- 1 α) h) 2))
(send setup set-editor-margin 0 0)
(send setup set-scaling α α)
(current-ps-setup setup)

(define dc (new pdf-dc%
                [interactive #f]
                [use-paper-bbox #f]
                [width w]
                [height h]
                [output "./foo.pdf"]))

(send dc start-doc "file output")
(send dc start-page)

(send (current-ps-setup) set-margin 0 0) 
(send (current-ps-setup) set-scaling 1 1)
(send (current-ps-setup) set-translation 0 0)
(send (current-ps-setup) set-editor-margin 0 0)

(send dc set-transformation
      (vector (send dc get-initial-matrix)
              0  h  ; x origin, y origin
              1  -1  ; x scale, y scale
              0))   ; rotation

(send dc draw-line 0 0 150 150)
(send dc draw-line 0 200 200 0)

(send dc end-page)
(send dc end-doc)
```

Comment: Scroll to see the final lines.

Comment: Thank you! I definitely misunderstood what the documentation was saying about the `use-paper-bbox #f` option. This is a very helpful clarification.